# Not displaying number of answers when searching

Tags: support, search

While searching, the result sometimes don't show the number of answers.

I am confused: **why the the number of answers is not displaying**?

As now when I search *[javascript grid](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20grid)* we just get the number of answer in first and third list:

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because search result is showing both questions and answers list. If you want to search only questions list add `is:question` in the search box [like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20grid%20is:question)

As @bfavaretto mentioned: You can determine whether it is question or answer by it's prefix.

Comment: Also, question titles are prefixed by `Q:`, and answer titles are prefixed by `A:`.

Comment: Thanks, again one more question. is there a reason for not displaying tags(given to the question) on answer.

Comment: @vusan - Can't say why but you can search for questions or answers withing specific tags.

Comment: @vusan tags are part of a question, not answer hence have no place in the "answer view" used to display answer information. You might start new feature request to add the tags (in search results only) to the view, but doubt it will be very popular.